# How to update data before using a custom TableViewCell button to perform a segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

Currently, I have a screen that shows a TableView with custom cells that each contain a **timeButton**. When you press the timeButton, it segues to a pop-up screen to select a time. When it's dismissed, it updates timeButton's title on the main screen.

I have a delegate method that updates **rowIndex** (instance var) with the indexPath.row of the pressed timeButton every time its pressed. I noticed that the segue method runs before **rowIndex** is updated by pressedTimeButton(cell: TaskCell) delegate method. How can I have the delegate method update the **rowIndex** before the segue occurs?

Here is the main VC's code:

```
struct Task {
    var name, time: String
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var taskList: UITableView!
    
    var tasks = [Task]()
    var rowIndex = Int()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set initial task time's value
        tasks.append(Task(name: "", time: "Set time"))
        
        taskList.delegate = self
        taskList.dataSource = self
    }

    // Segue to pop-up screen
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueToPopUp" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! PopUpViewController
            
            // ISSUE: rowIndex isn't updated when segue starts
            if tasks[rowIndex].time != "Set time" {    
                // if time is already set, reset time to "0:00"
                tasks[rowIndex].time = "0:00"
            } else {
                // if time is not set 
            } 
    }
    
    // Unwind from pop-up screen
    @IBAction func unwindFromPopUp(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        // code to update "timeButton" with selected time
        tasks[rowIndex].time = controller.selectedTaskTime
        ...
    }
}

extension TaskListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    
    // Return custom cell + data to show in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        cell.delegate = self

        // Configure timeButton in taskCell
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.timeButton.setTitle(task.time, for: .normal)

        return cell
    }
}

extension TaskListViewController: TaskCellDelegate {
    // ISSUE: rowIndex updates after segue method instead of before 
    func pressedTimeButton(onCell cell: TaskCell) {
        if let indexPath = taskList.indexPath(for: cell) {
            rowIndex = indexPath.row        
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my custom cell's code + its delegate protocol:

```
protocol TaskCellDelegate: class {
    func pressedTimeButton(onCell cell: TaskCell)
}

class TaskCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    weak var delegate: TaskCellDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timeButton: UIButton!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        delegate = nil
    }
    
    @IBAction func tapTimeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.pressedTimeButton(onCell: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like you have set segue from tableView cell to `PopUpViewController` on storyboard, what it does is it triggers the segue as soon as cell is tapped, rather drag a segue from ViewController to `PopUpViewController` that way segue will be performed only when you call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToPopUp", sender: nil)` also implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ` this method will be triggered when cell is tapped, perform your task time update and then call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToPopUp", sender: nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you have set segue from tableView cell/timeButton  to `PopUpViewController` in storyboard, what it does is it triggers the segue as soon as cell/timeButton is tapped, rather drag a segue from `ViewController` to `PopUpViewController` that way segue will be performed only when you call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToPopUp", sender: nil)`

[image]

also implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` (if you want the segue to be performed when cell is tapped) this method will be triggered when cell is tapped, perform your task time update.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        rowIndex = indexPath.row      
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToPopUp", sender: nil)
}
```

If you don't want segue on cell tap and instead need segue only on time button tap your existing `pressedTimeButton` method should work fine now

```
extension TaskListViewController: TaskCellDelegate {
      func pressedTimeButton(onCell cell: TaskCell) {
        if let indexPath = taskList.indexPath(for: cell) {
            rowIndex = indexPath.row
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToPopUp", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the segue on time button tap ended up working out perfectly after I adjusted where the segue was being triggered from, thank you for the suggestions Sandeep!

Comment: Am glad I could help :)